# next-intl: Issue with `useTranslation` in Shared Components Deployed to Vercel

Tags: next-intl

I'd like to start by expressing my gratitude for the next-intl library. It's been immensely helpful and I truly appreciate the work put into it. Thank you!

I'm currently utilizing a shared component and implementing `useTranslation` in it as follows:

```
// Not on the client side
function SomeComponent() {
  const t = useTranslations("topPage");
  return <div>{t("test")}</div>;
}
```

However, upon deploying to Vercel, I encounter an error during the build process, affecting all components that use `useTranslation` in a shared component.

```
Error: Usage of next-intl APIs in Server Components currently opts into dynamic rendering. This limitation will eventually be lifted, but as a stopgap solution, you can use the `unstable_setRequestLocale` API to enable static rendering, see https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/getting-started/app-router-server-components#static-rendering
-- [Error Trace]
```

I have reviewed the documentation (https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/getting-started/app-router#static-rendering) and understand the necessity of adding `unstable_setRequestLocale` to all layouts and pages.

My question is whether we should also add `unstable_setRequestLocale` to every shared component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to call `unstable_setRequestLocale` in the component itself but in the `page.tsx` or `layout.tsx`. Also, This step requires exporting `generateStaticParams` function.

```js
// app/page.tsx to opt out dynamic rendering in this page

import {locals} from "path/to/constants";

export function generateStaticParams() {
  return localse.map(locale => ({ locale }))
}

export default function Page({params}) {
  unstable_setRequestLocale(params.locale)

  return <div>content</div>
}
```

Comment: So I just need to ignore the build time error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I confirm this issue, when you create not-found.js file, make sure you have it under the [locale] directory, and make sure you don't call for `unstable_setRequestLocale(locale);` in that file if you have this call already in _app.tsx or layout.tsx files